# how to Process migration in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, process, metasploit

Is it possible to migrate/inject (into) another process memory space using python? I am new to python I know it's possible in c is there any working method or documentation on process migration in python?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built into Python. There might be a library, but you can always just call C functions with `ctypes`. But are you sure you are using the correct terminology? Process migration appears to be something different to what you are describing. Also, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to know if I can do this in Python like metasploit?

Comment: there are things like a [dll injector](https://github.com/infodox/python-dll-injection) for python, but it would be much harder if your aim was to run python code in another process